# Dynamic rate tables: How to change multiplied cell by drop down list

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

My goal is to have an average value (returned by 2 user inputted values) to be multiplied by a unique rate that is from either of 2 tables.

| Sales # | Sales $ | Avg.Tkt | Rate | AX Rate | MR Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | $10,000 | $100 | ? | ? | ? |

I have 2 drop-down lists: The 1st representing 2 tables (Table 1 & Table 2) and the 2nd representing the columns withing Tables 1 & Tables 2 (Healthcare, Education, Etc.)

| Table 1 | Healthcare | Education |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rate | 2.00% | 3.00% |
| AX Rate | 2.50% | 4.00% |
| MR Rate | 3.00% | 4.50% |

| Table 2 | Healthcare | Education |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rate | 2.50% | 3.50% |
| AX Rate | 3.00% | 4.50% |
| MR Rate | 3.50% | 5.00% |

I want it to when a user selects "Table 1" from the 1st drop-down list and "Healthcare" from the 2nd drop-down list it will call the rate in Table 1 - Healthcare cell multiply the Avg.tkt by the rate from Table 1 - Healthcare column (i.e. 2.00% x $100) and return it in a new cell.

I've already achieved this by nest IF statements:

```
=IF(C4="Table1",IF(C5="Healthcare",D31*J7,IF(C5="Education",D31*K7,C5="Charity",D31*L7),IF(C4="Table2",IF(C5="Healthcare",D31*J7,IF(C5="Education",D31*K7,C5="Charity",D31*L7)))))
```

But would like to know if there is a more efficient way of producing these results?
I would like to reduce the use of nesting IF statements (or at least cut down on the amount).

Comment: VLOOKUP, XLOOKUP and INDEX MATCH are all things you may want to...um... lookup

Comment: Your nested IF statements formula is not valid, not sure if you've pasted it incorrectly but if I copy it into Excel, I get a 'you've entered too many arguments' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to or can't join the tables together as another answer suggested, you could use an IF statement and nest an INDEX and MATCH formula within:

```
=IF($B$4="Table 1",INDEX($A$7:$C$10,MATCH(D$1,$A$7:$A$10,0),MATCH($B$5,$A$7:$C$7,0)),INDEX($A$12:$C$15,MATCH(D$1,$A$12:$A$15,0),MATCH($B$5,$A$12:$C$12,0)))
```

This checks whether the table selected is Table 1. If it is then it looks up that rate metric for that specific industry in the Table 1 range of data. If the dropdown is not Table 1, it is Table 2 so it does the same lookup but for the Table 2 range of data.

[image: Screenshot of Excel solution using an IF statement with an INDEX and MATCH formula nested within.]

Answer (score 1):

In `Excel` there are **multitude** of approaches to resolve a problem. Using **Table Names** with `INDIRECT()` Function can also be accomplished, however using `INDIRECT()` can be avoided as it is **single-threaded** and so defeats `Excel’s` **multi-threaded calculation engine**. Still I am sharing the solution along with the other ways, you can try the one best suits with your query.

---

[image]

---

**Approach One:** --> Using `INDIRECT()` & `TOROW()`

---

• Formula used in cell `H4` --> It spills to right!

```
=TOROW(INDIRECT(E1&"["&F1&"]"))
```

---

• Or, Formula used in cell `H9` --> Without `#SPILL!` --> It needs to fill right!

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT($E$1&"["&$F$1&"]"),COLUMN(A1))
```

---

**Approach Two:** --> Using `XLOOKUP()` with `INDEX()` and `CHOOSE()` or `IF()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H14` --> Using `IF()`

```
=INDEX(XLOOKUP($F$1,TableOne[#Headers],
IF($E$1="TableOne",TableOne,TableTwo)),COLUMN(A1))
```

---

• Or, Formula used in cell `H19` --> Using `CHOOSE()`

```
=INDEX(XLOOKUP($F$1,TableOne[#Headers],
CHOOSE(N($E$1<>"TableOne")+1,TableOne,TableTwo)),COLUMN(A1))
```

---

**Note:** In all of the above formulas I am referencing structured table viz. **TableOne** & **TableTwo** . Please adjust the ranges as per your suit.

---

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to join those 2 tables and change structure a bit so you can avoid `IF` statements (imagine if you need to use even more tables) and use something like this:

```
=SUM(($D$9:$E$9=D4)*($B$10:$B$15=C4)*($C$10:$C$15=E4)*($D$10:$E$15))
```

Result:

[image]

Use that "filtered" value for your further calculations.